# Flutter doesn't reinstall my app on device even after running flutter clean on android studio

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

Flutter doesn't reinstall my app on my device after uninstall but runs the app on the device even after flutter clean on android studio

Tried flutter clean

I want the app to be installed on my device

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm finding this confusing. You say it doesn't reinstall after uninstall, but that it does run the app after clean. If it's running, that means it's installed. Also, `flutter clean` doesn't uninstall the app from your device but rather just cleans the build directory. Did you mean that after uninstalling, the only way you can get it to reinstall is by running `flutter clean` before running `flutter run`?

Comment: The app was installed on my device, then I uninstalled it from my android device and ran the code(usb debugging), the app did not reinstall on my device but it would load and display. The issue is fixed now anyway, I restarted my device and it worked.

Comment: Okay glad it worked. As I said, if it was displaying on the device it had to be installed there, it's more likely the app just wasn't showing up in the app drawer for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I've also faced the same issue. The only way for me to solve this was to uninstall the app from ADB:
adb uninstall com.package.name

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/28780